# Oracle : How to export the database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export, oracle-apex

So I am using oracle 11g and I am unable to figure out how to export my tables and all.. I am able to export forms but i don't know how to do the same with everything else.. What I did was I went on Application Builder - Export - Workspace - Export workspace. It downloaded an sql file but whenever I try exporting that file on a different account, I always get the following error

```
File is not a valid Application Express application export file.
```

What I do to import the file is go to application Builder - Import - browse the file - Next - and then I get that error message. What do I do?

Comment: You're referencing Application Express screens and features. To answer your question, we need to know what you intend to use your database export for - to create a new database, populate an existing one, use as a backup for your existing? Do you want the objects AND the data, just the data, etc? There are many export and backup utilities available for Oracle Database. Google 'data pump', 'rman', 'export', 'sql developer', etc. to get an idea.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith just for submitting a uni assignment.  I have sql developer. If I click on export database.. Will that do the required work? Is there a way for me to test it?

Comment: if you just need to give your PROF a script to create your objects and data - yes, it should work. To test it, run the script in an empty schema/new user account. make sure the order of creates/inserts is to you and your prof's liking, would hate for you to get an F b/c it tries to insert a record in a child table before a parent and it fails with an ORA-

Answer (score 0):

If you export the whole schema (and that's what you're looking for, isn't it? You have to give everything to your professor), you shouldn't worry about import because data is imported first. After that, Oracle creates ("imports") foreign key constraints.